# How would I find Ancestry/Ethnicity data by state on Census.gov?

Tags: government, demographics, statistics, census

I am trying to find out, on a state-by-state (city/county as well, if possible) basis, what the population makeup is based on ancestry/ethnicity (i.e. Polish). For example, "what percentage of the population of Illinois in 2020 was of Polish ancestry?"

However, I have only been able to find this data at a national level. I can see that sites such as [statisticalatlas.com](https://statisticalatlas.com/state/Illinois/Ancestry) have the information I'm looking for and cite Census.gov as being where they got it. But I need to cite an official government source for what I'm doing and I haven't been able to find the exact census product which they are citing for state level data.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What _have_ you found at census.gov?

Comment: The statistics I need, but only zoomed out - the percentage of nationwide population with given ethnic or national ancestry.

Comment: Did you look at the 2010 data?  I think I've seen what you are looking for, so I wonder whether the relevant data from 2020 are still in preparation.

Comment: I was looking for *any* data. I wasn't able to find this data for any year, 1990, 2000, 2010... I guess the problem is that I'm really not sure how to navigate Census.gov. Other than using the search bar and putting in "ancestry by state" or similar searches....

Answer (score 3):

The page you are looking for (if you want all the data for all states and ancestries is

https://data.census.gov/cedsci/table?t=-A0%20-%20All%20available%20ancestries&g=0100000US%240400000&tid=ACSSPP1Y2010.S0201

To find it, go to https://data.census.gov/cedsci/table and, in the left column, select Geography -> State and Topics -> Populations and People/
Ancestry/ Select Ancestry

Then, in the right column, click on "American Community Survey" and select the year you want to see.

It probably makes sense to select only a single state and ancestry at a time, as otherwise the table will be very large - you get a crosstabulation with all the other demographics criteria from that survey.

Answer (score 2):

You can either view the data table (as ccprog explains), or view the state "Profile".

To do that, visit https://data.census.gov/cedsci/, click the "Map" link, which will take you to an [interactive map](https://data.census.gov/cedsci/map?vintage=2020&loc=38.8800,-98.0000,z3.0000).  From there, you can click on a state, then select "View Profile".

Each state's profile includes a section for "Ancestry" information, near the top of the page.